# Spring boot Tests: how to up context only 1 time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-test

I want to use only 1 context for all tests. Than, I inherit all test classes of `AbstractTest`:

```
@SpringBootTest
public abstract class AbstractTest {
}
```

I expect that context will be up only time, but it up for every package. I have 5 packages, & context up 5 times.

[image]

How to up context only 1 time & to save packages structure?

UPD: test example:

```
@Test
void create() throws Exception {
    Car car = entityGenerator.createCar(profile.getId());
    String content = asJson(car);
    log.info(content);
    result = mockMvc.perform(
            post("/v1/car/add")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(content)
    )
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").isNumber())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.profileId").value(car.getProfileId()))
            .andReturn();

    assertEquals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, result.getResponse().getContentType());
}
```

Comment: there are a few reasons why context is loaded more than once.. could you please show your tests examples

Comment: @Ruslan added example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Test uses a [Context Caching mechanism](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching) to reuse already started contexts if the context configuration matches. So by default, you should be fine with having one abstract class or just by annotating your tests with `@SpringBootTest`. The package where the test or production code is in, shouldn't matter.

There are however scenarios where Spring Test will create a new context if you change something for the context configuration e.g. use `@MockBean` or set the active profile.

Take a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching) and you can find the list of configuration parameters Spring Test uses to identify a context. If one of these parameters changes throughout your tests, you'll get a new context created.

Also ensure that your tests are executed within the same context and you are not using any `forkMode` of the Maven Surefire plugin.